# What DDAL adventure has Cape of the Mountebank as treasure?

Tags: dnd-5e, treasure, dnd-adventurers-league

I'm trying to get some order in my D&D 5th edition DDAL character and writing down his adventures in order, as opposed to written on various notes tucked in random locations of my folder.

However, one of my notes only mentions that I'm to receive a **Cape of the Mountebank**, a Potion of Greater Healing, 2625 XP and 400 GP, when I reach 5th level.

Any idea what public play adventure that could be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1omoTExpdh7cdiq9NnfVpf6-CnAkGRbA-FMIiNaZXpvg/edit#gid=1684901685) (not mine) lists rewards for Adventurers League adventures.

DDAL4-07 “The Innocent” (part 7 of *Misty Fortunes and Absent Hearts*) has a Cape of the Mountebank listed as a faction reward.